# Matplotlib - Plotting Normal Distribution alongside Random Points

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to plot a normal distribution alongside some randomly generated points that conform to that distribution. I want those points to simply be plotted on the x-axis to show where density of observations exist, like this:

[image]

How do I achieve this? I keep getting some type errors with the code below:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean = 64.43
standard_deviation = 2.99
random_weights = [norm(mean, standard_deviation) for _ in range(0,30)]

x_axis = np.arange(50.0, 80.0, 0.01)

plt.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis, mean, standard_deviation))
plt.scatter(random_weights, [0 for _ in range(0,30)])
plt.show()
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\git\python_playground\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    plt.scatter(random_weights, [0 for _ in range(0,30)])
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3068, in scatter
    __ret = gca().scatter(
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1361, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4587, in scatter
    collection = mcoll.PathCollection(
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 1034, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 431, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 206, in __init__
    offsets = np.asanyarray(offsets, float)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 171, in asanyarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'rv_frozen'
```

UPDATE:

Here was the full code solution based on marked answer below.

```
from scipy.stats import norm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mean = 64.43
standard_deviation = 2.99
random_weights = np.random.normal(mean, standard_deviation, 30)

# Plot between -10 and 10 with .01 steps.
x_axis = np.arange(50.0, 80.0, 0.01)

plt.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis, mean, standard_deviation))
plt.scatter(random_weights, [0 for _ in range(0,30)])
plt.show()
```

Comment: *"I keep getting some type errors ..."* Whenever you have a question about errors, include the complete traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`norm(mean, standard_deviation)` does not generate random samples from the normal distribution.  For random samples, use the `rvs()` method, e.g. `normal(mean, standard_deviation).rvs()`, or `norm.rvs(mean, standard_deviation)`.  Or use the numpy random number generators.

Also, the `rvs` method accepts a `size` parameter, so instead of the explicit loop, you can write

```
random_weights = norm.rvs(mean, standard_deviation, size=30)
```

---

Off topic: I think your scatter plot of the points on the x axis will reflect the relation with the density better if you add `alpha=0.5` (or some other fraction--experiment) to the `scatter` function call.

Comment: Oops. I guess I'm confusing my PDF, CDF, and reverse CDF functions between 3 different libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You stored 30 normal random variables in the list. I think you intended to  plot 30 random observations from one normal random variable.

```py
# Draw 30 samples from a normal distribution
mean = 64.43
standard_deviation = 2.99
random_weights = norm(mean, standard_deviation).rvs(30) # Use .rvs()

x_axis = np.arange(50.0, 80.0, 0.01)
plt.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis, mean, standard_deviation))
plt.scatter(random_weights, [0 for _ in range(0,30)])
plt.show()
```